# Monogdb Crashes having Multiple Connection using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Server.js File :

```
var option = {
    server: {
        poolSize: 10,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            auto_reconnect:true
        }
    },
    replset: {
        poolSize: 10,
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            auto_reconnect:true
        }
    }
};

var mongoURI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/duplicacySecond';
mongoose.connect(mongoURI, option).then(function(){
    console.log("sucessfully connected to mongoDB");
}, function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log('not connected to the database : '+err);
    }
});
```

user.js for mongoose model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  userName : { type :String, unique:true},
  password : { type :String},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

Web service for inserting my data in mongodb database :

```
var User = require('../models/user');

var user = new User();
user.userName = req.body.userName;
user.password = req.body.password;
user.save(function(err){
    resp.json({success:true, message:'User successfully created'});
});
```

Mongo DB Crashes and last entry of log files shows 2017-09-18T07:39:36.249+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57774 #115 (115 connections now open)
i am using node mongoose and its connect method.
i don't know how to resolve this issue, if any one can help me then please let me know.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Your programming team really needs to talk to each other. Please don't all post the same questions on StackOverflow. [Crash- having multiple connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46275401/2313887). You need to give more context. How exactly is that connection code being used? What type of application is this. Honestly, you should be able to produce a small and complete listing that replicates the issue. It's likely you are actually calling connect multiple times.

Comment: Honestly you are not helping by posting such long comments, and particularly using formatting that makes me feel like this is "cookie cutter" and you and your team member are just posting this "everywhere". Make edits to your question, and don't post long comments. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Making it clear. One of these questions needs to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @NeilLunn that situation is because of Ram, which i have updated. now my server is not crashing any more but now it consumes too much ram and buff/cache of my system please suggest is there any solution for this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of that situation, actually the problem is not about mongodb or other technology but the problem is of Physical Memory of System.